# Sorting a list based on whether item is odd or even

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of numbers depending on whether it is odd or even (even gains higher priority). 
Example:

```
a=[1,2,3,4] 
a.sort(key=org(a)) sorted will produce [2,4,1,3]. I want to use the sort method 

def org(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i]%2==0:
            b.append(a[i])
            b.sort()
    else:
        c.append(a[i])
        c.sort()
    print(b+c)
```

I got this error from running a.sort(key=org(a))

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#80>", line 1, in <module>
a.sort(key=org(a))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I realize that sorting it every time makes it slow. Which other way can I do this without having to sort after every loop?

Answer (score 7):

To sort by "evenness" and then by magnitude, you can use a function that returns a `tuple`

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4] 
>>> a.sort(key=lambda x: (x % 2, x))
>>> a
[2, 4, 1, 3]
```

To sort the odd entries first, you can simply negate the value of the modulus. This is a useful trick for reversing the sort of numeric fields in general.

```
>>> a.sort(key=lambda x:(-(x % 2), x))
>>> a
[1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Comment: So what if I want odd numbers with higher priority?

Comment: put `x+1 % 2` in your key argument's lambda function instead of `x%2`.

Comment: Perhaps `(x+1) % 2`, since `%` happens before `+`.

Comment: Yes, good call thank you @Akavall :) I thought it would evaluate the other way for some reason.

Comment: @rofls, if you want to avoid parens, you could use `~x % 2`, but that is for a very specific situation

Comment: @JohnLaRooy, ooh nice it looks like that literally flips the bits :) I even get -11 when I do ~10, which I assume is because of two's complement method of storing numbers. Very clever, though indeed specific.

Comment: `~x % 2` is  clever and works, but it works because Python returns positive modulus of negative numbers `-3 % 2 => 1`, while most compiled languages return negative modulus `-3 % 2 => -1`. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were on the right track:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> sorted(a,key=lambda x: x%2)
[2, 4, 1, 3]
```

Here `sorted` is a function that returns a sorted list. You can also use the `sort` method, as John said. Apparently if your original list is not sorted, `sorted` will not work, so you then you would have to do:

```
a = [3,2,1,4]
a.sort()
newList = sorted(a,key=lambda x: x%2)
```

at which point John's code is probably cleaner. His can also be implemented with the `sorted` function though, by doing `sorted(a,key=lambda x: (x%2,x))`.

Comment: This is ok if the original `a` is already in sorted order, as `sort` is stable

Comment: I'm getting [1, 2, 3, 4] instead of [1,3,2,4] ??

Comment: Sorry, do `sorted(a,key=lambda x: (x+1)%2)`

Comment: Or the same with the `sort` method, to sort odd first. Oh, and you'll still want @JohnLaRooy's tuple bit. So, `sorted(a,key=lambda x: ((x+1)%2,x))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
one can use helper function from intertools 

def partition_by_pred(pred, iterable):
    from itertools import tee, filterfalse
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)

l, r = partition_by_pred(lambda x: False if x % 2 == 0  else True ,[1,2,3,4]  )

print(*l,*r)

2 4 1 3
```